# user data persistance without account

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies

what I'm looking for is solution like on codepen - where I can create new pen and as long as I don't clean my browsers cookies - i have option to save it. but if I share It with a friend by sending url - he only have FORK option.
So I don't need registeration at all, but only kind of cookie / session solution? Or just send this id req body?

Also user can 'own' a few pens - so on a backend in my db I should have a table with `cookie-id: [ids-of-pens]` ?

My app is using nodejs + expressjs + postgress (knexjs) and I'm pretty lost with solutions for user registeration.

Best

Comment: You will need to associate your "codepen" data, stored on your backend, with an `id` or `guid` you can then call and reference from web server i.e `mycodepen.com?id=1` the fork will simply be cloning the original data on your backend with a newly associated `id` i.e `mycodepen.com?id=2`

Comment: yeah, that works now, but as you can see on codepen you can edit & save your 'pen' without having account - there is a cookie in browser that allows you to do that. but I don't now how the flow should look like

Comment: You can use local storage to add previously ‘saved’ links to the codepens. A cookie can just be something you check and determine if that user is returning i.e has data to retrieve from the local store or you could store the codepen url in the cookie and redirect to that if present. Again, just an example.

Comment: Thats the good direction, but the main issue is something another. Lets assume that I create a new 'pen' and It gets id: 2 from the backend. But I want to change a & b so I want to do PUT onto server. In the meantime, I send you the link to this pen, and you can open it but can't edit at this URL, while I in my browser with saved cookie can do It. Just looking for stack that can help me with this, I look at express session etc.